# How to ignore test projects in a Visual Studio dependency validation diagrams

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, diagram

I've created an architecture diagram using Visual Studio's Architecture/New Dependency Validation Diagram.

All seems fine and dandy except that I'm unable to find a way to exclude my test projects (and my dependency injection project) as the tests (and DI) don't really matter to me as far as architecture validation goes.

I've taken a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/validate-code-with-layer-diagrams?view=vs-2019#manage-validation-errors) and done a fair bit of googling yet haven't managed to find anything immediately useful.

If you have any ideas or superior Googling skills your help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Diagram and issues]

Using Visual Studio Enterprise, 2019 v16.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add DV2002 to the suppress warnings section of the Build properties of the project your working on.[Click for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUDeh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution was to remove the references to the Architecture Diagram in the projects I didn't want it applied to.

So for any Test (and my DI) projects I simply opened the .csproj file and removed:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="..\WDX.Config.Architecture\DependencyValidation.layerdiagram" Link="DependencyValidation.layerdiagram">
        <Visible>False</Visible>
    </AdditionalFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

Although Visual Studio then keeps showing this:
[image]

So I'm still on the lookout for a better solution.